# How can I export a room database and upload it on Firebase storage (and then download it and import)?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage, android-room

I want to add a function to export the database file, upload it to Firebase storage, and then, with a click, download the database file and replace (or import) it to the current database.

I don't know if my way is the best or not, but this is code that I am trying to work on it. This code is trying to save the database to the SD card (external storage).

I don’t need to use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and don't have any need to save on local storage. Just Firebase storage, directly. Plus, I did not test this code yet, because my phone is [Android 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_11) and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not working on it. So maybe the code is not working at all, I don't know.

```
private fun importDB() {
    try {

        val sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        val data = Environment.getDataDirectory()
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            val currentDBPath = ("//data//" + "PackageName"
                    + "//databases//" + "DatabaseName")
            val backupDBPath = "/BackupFolder/DatabaseName"
            val backupDB = File(data, currentDBPath)
            val currentDB = File(sd, backupDBPath)
            val src = FileInputStream(currentDB).channel
            val dst = FileOutputStream(backupDB).channel
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size())
            src.close()
            dst.close()
            Toast.makeText(
                baseContext, backupDB.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()
    }
}

//exporting database
private fun exportDB() {
    val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
        .child("database/${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid}")
    try {
        val sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        val data = Environment.getDataDirectory()
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            val currentDBPath = ("//data//" + "PackageName"
                    + "//databases//" + "DatabaseName")
            val backupDBPath = "/BackupFolder/DatabaseName"
            val currentDB = File(data, currentDBPath)
            val backupDB = File(sd, backupDBPath)
            val src = FileInputStream(currentDB).channel
            val dst = FileOutputStream(backupDB).channel
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size())
            src.close()
            dst.close()
            Toast.makeText(
                baseContext, backupDB.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()
    }
}
```